# Most efficient way to generate "ordered subsets" of a sequence

Tags: python

I need to generate all "ordered subsets" (apologies if I'm not using correct mathematical terminology) of a sequence in Python, with omitted elements replaced with `None`.Given `[1, 2]`, I want `[(1, 2), (1, None), (None, 2), (None, None)]`. Each "ordered subset" should have the property that at each position, it is either exactly the same element as in the seed sequence, or it is `None`.

I can fairly easily generate subsets with omitted elements missing with the following:

```
from itertools import combinations
for length in xrange(len(items), 0, -1):
    for combination in combinations(items, length):
        yield combination
```

I can't figure out what the most effective way of reconstructing the missing elements, would be though. My first thought is to do something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
indexes = range(len(items))
for length in xrange(len(items), 0, -1):
    for combination in combinations(indexes, length):
        yield tuple(items[i] if i in combination else None for i in indexes)
```

Just wondering if anyone can spot any obvious deficiencies in this, or if there's a more efficient solution I've missed. (Note that the `items` will be a fairly short list, typically under 10 elements, so I am not concerned about the O(N) search of "combination" in the inner loop).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
from itertools import product, repeat
given = [1, 2]
with_nones = zip(given, repeat(None))
print(list(product(*with_nones)))
```

Comment: Since I love generators, I'll use a version with `izip_longest` -- but awesome, thanks!

Comment: +1.  Here's the `izip_longest` version (based on dcrosta's comment): `list(product(*izip_longest(given, [])))`

Comment: this is in the wrong order tho: `[(None, None), (None, 2), (1, None), (1, 2)]`

Comment: @carrot-top: Fixed, I overlooked the part that said "*ordered* subsets".

Comment: @JoelCornett: Yup! There it is! +1

Comment: I don't care about the order of the subsets, just the order of elements within each one, as it turns out. I'm using something very like Steven Rumbalski's solution, but without `list(...)`, since I only need to iterate once

Answer (score 2):

You could start with an empty list, for every element in your seed you can copy all the final lists and add the seed at the end.

e.g.

```
solutions = []
solutions.append([])
for elem in seed:
    newPartials = []
    for partial in solutions:
        newPartial = partial[:]
        newPartial.append(elem)
        newPartials.append(newPartial)
    solutions.extend(newPartials)
```

or, you could create the number of possible solutions, `2^n`, where `n` is the length of your seed list, and using modular arithmetic, remove elements, like so:

```
solutions = []
for i in xrange(2**n):
    solutions.append(seed[:])
seedLen = len(seed)
for i in xrange(2**(n-1)): // % 0 case of following loop
    solutions[i].pop(0)
for elemLoc in xrange(1,seedLen):
    for solutionNum in xrange(2**n):
        if solutionNum % elemLoc = 0:
            solutions[solutionNum].pop(elemLoc)
```

This solution is hilariously inefficient, I mostly included it because it's an interesting way to solve the problem.

Comment: One of my co-workers proposed a one-liner version of your first suggestion -- took me a while to unravel it: `reduce(lambda x,y: x+[e+[y] for e in x], items, [[]]))`

Comment: I was specifically going for understandability over elegance when they conflicted. Neat tricks are for people who know what they're doing, and sometimes not even then.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate -- in case you want to show off how silly you are to NOT use itertools:

```
>>> given=[1,2]
>>> gz=zip(given,[None]*len(given))
>>> [(i,j) for i in gz[0] for j in gz[1]]
[(1, 2), (1, None), (None, 2), (None, None)]
```

Comment: Neat. Can you generalize it to more than a 2-element `given` though?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another:

```
>>> given=[1,2,3,4]
>>> rtr=[[]]
>>> for t in map(None,*(given,[None])):
...    rtr=[x+[y] for x in rtr for y in t]
... 
>>> rtr
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, None], [1, 2, None, 4], [1, 2, None, None], [1, None, 3, 4], [1, None, 3, None], [1, None, None, 4], [1, None, None, None], [None, 2, 3, 4], [None, 2, 3, None], [None, 2, None, 4], [None, 2, None, None], [None, None, 3, 4], [None, None, 3, None], [None, None, None, 4], [None, None, None, None]]
```